Print latest date based on Max value in case where there are lot of Max Value in columns
I would like to resolve this issues.
I have a table with columns name's Table1[Time_Code] and Table1[Fact_Value], the issue is when I try to identify Max Table1[Fact_Value]  sometime where are lot of Max value in the same columns, me I wouldlike juste to print Max Table1[Fact_Value] corresponding to latest Table1[Time_Code].



Time_Code
Fact_Valu




1990
22


1991
22


1992
17


1993
4



the printing year will be 1991
I try this is but he doesn't reflect my expected year
My expected value will be 1991 due to Max value and note 1990 or anything
My expected value will be 1991 due to Max value and note 1990 or anything

Not sure exactly what you want.
But to return the Table Row that contains the max Time_Code corresponding to the max Fact_Valu you can use Power Query:
Original Table

Algorithm

Filter the table to include only the rows containing `MAX(Fact_Valu)'
Return the MAX(Time_Code) from that filtered table

M Code
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Time_Code", Int64.Type}, {"Fact_Valu", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Select Max Value" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Fact_Valu] = List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Fact_Valu])),
    #"Select Max Time_Code" = Table.SelectRows(#"Select Max Value", each [Time_Code] = List.Max(#"Select Max Value"[Time_Code]))
in
    #"Select Max Time_Code"

Result

If you want to use DAX to just output the relevant year (perhaps for a card visual), you can use the DAX formula:
  CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Time_Code]),'Table'[Fact_Valu]=MAX('Table'[Fact_Valu]))



Great, much appreciate it work properly. Thanks
I used DAX formula

@Stéphane Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See What should I do when someone answers my question.
